# How to Create Filter for a User group in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to create filters for a certain group of users. Basically only they should be able to view that filter in the filter area.

I tried something like this,

```
<filter icon="terp-check" domain="[('state','=','Current')]" string="Current Bills"  groups="my_module.group_sales_manager" />
```

Its not working. According to this only group_sales_manager should be able to use this filter, Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
<filter icon="terp-check" 
        domain="[('state','=','Current')]"
        string="Current Bills"
        groups="base.group_sale_manager" />
```

*"Current Bills"* filter will be used by Sale Manager User.